# Minimum value of probability of events

Tags: probability, inequality

I have to prove the following -:

For any two events A and B, show that
$$(P(A∩B))^2 +(P(A∩B'))^2 +(P(A' ∩B))^2 +(P(A' ∩B'))^2 ≥ 1/4$$

$X' := X^C$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $(P(AB))^2+(P(AB^c))^2+(P(A^cB))^2+(P(A^cB^c))^2\ge\frac{1}{4}$ for any events $A$ and $B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114667/proving-pab2pabc2pacb2pacbc2-ge-frac14-for-any)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^C)+P(A^C \cap B)+P(A^C \cap B^C)=1$$

What combination of these minimizes the sum?